# Undefined local variable or method `product_price'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Приветствую. Начал разбираться с RoR.

Получил ошибку:

```
app/views/carts/show.html.erb where line #11 raised:

undefined local variable or method `product_price' for #<LineItem:0x00000004de5ef0>
```

app/models/line_item.rb

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart

  def total_price
    product_price * quantity
  end

end
```

app/views/carts/show.html.erb

```
<% if notice %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>
    <h2>Корзина</h2>
    <table>
      <% @cart.line_items.each do |item| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= item.quantity %> &times;</td>
        <td><%= item.product.title %></td>
        <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(item.total_price) %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
      <tr class="total_line">
        <td colspan="2">Total</td>
        <td class="total_call"><%= number_to_currency(@cart.total_price) %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <ul>    
      <li><%= item.quantity %> Х <%= item.product.title %></li>
    </ul>

    <%= button_to 'Empty cart', @cart, metod: :delete, data: {confirm:'A you shure?'} %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_cart_path(@cart) %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', carts_path %>
```

Что я делаю не так?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Либо вы пытаетесь обратиться к полю product_price модели LineItem - в таком случае проверьте, есть ли такое поле у данной модели, потому что похоже на то, что оно отсутствует.
2. Либо вы пытаетесь обратиться к полю price модели Product, которая связана с моделью LineItem - в таком случае, если у модели Product есть поле price, к нему стоит обращаться таким образом:

`product.price * quantity`

Comment: у меня как раз 2й вариант. спасибо.